# how to setup syslogd for network equipment such as routers

Tags: syslog

I seen syslog server logging options on various pieces of equipment on my network. I was wondering how would I setup a syslog server for them to broadcast to? Is there anything special I need to do. I tried it with my netgear router i.e. typed in ip for a pc running ubuntu hardy which does use syslogd. However I don't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to,

1. configure syslogd to accept remote data
2. ensure you don't have a firewall in the way

I think Ubuntu uses `sysklogd`, and [this article seems](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/log-all-logs-to-central-linux-unix-loghost.html) to cover it.

You'll need to know if you want to sent TCP or UDP syslog messages (or both), and therefore which firewall (iptables) ports to open, etc.  That varies depending on the device sending the syslog data.

Some other detail in the [man page for sysklogd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/sysklogd.8.html).